# how to change text color dynamically depends on values using xaml for UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Xaml:

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind status}" Margin="30 5 0 0"  FontSize="15" Height="25" FontFamily="Praxis LT Regular" FontStyle="Normal"  />
   </StackPanel>
```

I want to change color for Status depends on values.Like if status is active then it should be green color,else if status is inactive it should be red color,or else it should be a orange color.

How to apply text for these conditions using xaml

Comment: What is the type status?

Comment: I got the result

Answer (score 1):

**XAML**

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="{x:Bind ((local:StatusVM)comboBox.SelectedItem).Status, Mode=OneWay}"
                   Foreground="{x:Bind ((local:StatusVM)comboBox.SelectedItem).GetColor(), Mode=OneWay}"
                   Margin="30 5 0 0" 
                   FontSize="15" Height="25" FontFamily="Praxis LT Regular" FontStyle="Normal"  />
    </StackPanel>
```

**C#**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        comboBox.ItemsSource = new List<StatusVM>()
        {
            new StatusVM{Status=Status.Active},
            new StatusVM{Status=Status.Inactive},
            new StatusVM{Status=Status.Other},

        };
    }
}
public enum Status
{
    Active = 0,
    Inactive = 1,
    Other = 2
}
public class StatusVM
{
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush GetColor()
        => Status == Status.Active
            ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
            : Status == Status.Inactive
            ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
            : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
    public override string ToString() => Status.ToString();
}
```